# If we remove last member from the group in Microsoft graph API, Will it also remove the group as well?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In Microsoft Graph API I have created 1 group and added a member too, when I try to remove that member from group (Which is last member in that group) the group is also deleted automatically.

Can anyone help me out with this like, Is it a normal behavior or Microsoft Graph API or something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the member from group allows only removing that particular member from the group using Graph API. It will not delete the Group automatically.

Make sure you are using the correct request to delete the member only.

DELETE [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members/{directory-object-id}/$ref](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup-id%7D/members/%7Bdirectory-object-id%7D/$ref)

Here **group-id** is object id of the group from where you want to delete the member and **directory-object-id** is the object id of the member you want to delete.

Comment: I have used the same and it is working if I test it manual but when I run my Postman Collection for E2E test cases for this scenario we got 404 error for group id
and the most amazing thing is that we have facing this issue on random time. like sometime it will run all the test cases perfectly but sometime it got failed